# function calling by rigid python keyword

Tags: python, list, object, variables, keyword

why list object is not callable inside a function ??

CODE:

```
def unique_list(list1):
    
    sets=set(list1)
    
    u_list=(list(sets))
    
    print("old list",list1)
    print('unique list',u_list)

list1=[1,1,2,3,4,4,5]
unique_list(list1)
```

when i did this.. I got the exact output `[1,2,3,4,5]...` BUT
if i use list in lieu of list1 or any other name  like the following code:

```
def unique_list(list):
     sets=set(list)
    u_list=(list(sets))
    print("old list",list)``
    print('unique list',u_list)

list=[1,1,2,3,4,4,5]
unique_list(list)
```

python throws error:

```
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

is it for this reason that rigid keywords must not be used as variable name ?? or for other reasons ??

Comment: Don't use `list` as name, this way you override the built-in function `list()` which you try to use inside the function. Same apply for all built-in functions, modules from Standard Library, etc.

Comment: Don't use reserved keywords anything except `list` would work

Comment: when you call `u_list=(list(sets))`, how do you expect Python to know that, on *this* line (but not the others), `list` is meant to be the built-in Python function rather than the function argument of the same name? The answer is: it can't.

Answer (score 1):

Heres working code for what you want to do

```
def unique_list(list1):
    print("old list",list1)
    print('unique list',(list(set(list1))))

list1=[1,1,2,3,4,4,5]
unique_list(list1)
```

---

****here's why your code wasn't working****

lets take a look at the code that defines your function

```
def unique_list(list):
    #code
```

`list` is a class name and `list()` is a function that is native to python; by making it a parameter and or variable, you are overriding it!

So, when you call `list(set(list))` its basically saying: `parameter(set(parameter))`

Obviously the parameter cant be a function and a list at the same time; so there isn't any scenario where this could work.

I recommend using convention names like so if you arent sure what to call a list:

```
lst = []
x = []
l = []
```

The **only** time you should ever put any of these names alone into the definition of a function is through `type-hinting`

```
def foo(s: str, l: list) -> list:
    #do code
    return l + list(s)
```

**In conclusion...** it's a horrible practice to use any built-in function/class names in python as variable/functions unless you are actually trying to override them.